# Execute a query multiple times

Tags: .net, dapper

According to the [Dapper documentation](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper#execute-a-command-multiple-times), I can execute the same command multiple times if I pass an `IEnumerable` parameter:

```
connection.Execute(@"insert MyTable(colA, colB) values (@a, @b)",
    new[] { new { a=1, b=1 }, new { a=2, b=2 }, new { a=3, b=3 } }
  ).IsEqualTo(3); // 3 rows inserted: "1,1", "2,2" and "3,3"
```

I would like to do something similar but with a Query. The same query would be executed multiple times and then the result of each execution, which would be a scalar value, would be combined in a `IEnumerable` result. Something like this:

```
IEnumerable<long> ids = connection.Query(@"insert MyTable(colA, colB) values (@a, @b);
                     select case(scope_identity() as bigint);",
    new[] { new { a=1, b=1 }, new { a=2, b=2 }, new { a=3, b=3 } }
  );
```

When I try to do this, I get an `InvalidOperationException` with the message "An enumerable sequence of parameters (arrays, lists, etc) is not allowed in this context".
Is there a way to accomplish this?

I am using Dapper 1.50.2.

Comment: The documentation is using `Execute` while you are trying to apply the same using `Query`. Documentation says nothing about being able to do the same with queries. Which I believe is the cause of your error

Comment: @Nkosi Yes, I know that the documentation is using `Execute` and the `Query` example does not work, at least the way it is. It is used just to represent what I am trying to accomplish

Comment: I understand that. I was explaining that the API does not provide that functionality. You could inspect the source code as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API does not provide that functionality. You would need to execute the query multiple times with each parameter argument.

```
var sql  = @"insert MyTable(colA, colB) values (@a, @b);
select case(scope_identity() as bigint);";
var parameters = new[] { new { a=1, b=1 }, new { a=2, b=2 }, new { a=3, b=3 } }; 
List<long> ids = new List<long>();    
foreach(var param in parameters) {
    ids.AddRange(connection.Query<long>(sql, param));
}
```